# On App Engine, how do you make an ndb Property immutable once set?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

This seems like such a commonplace requirement, it'd be builtin, but anyway: If you have a model like the following one, how do you stop the `eggs` property being mutated after it's been set?

```
class Spam(ndb.Model):

    eggs = ndb.StringProperty()
```

The goal is is to have the property **not** required, so it'd default to `None`, but once it's been mutated from `None`, to a string in the above case, it can never be changed again, but any insight into defining an immutable property would be appreciated.

I had considered using the `validator` argument of the `ndb.Property` to pass in a function; see the answers below for why that wouldn't work here. It's useful for understanding the objects and namespaces involved.

Answer (score 2):

One approach which does not require you to use custom properties is to use hooks See docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__post_get_hook

You would use a `_post_get_hook(cls, key, future)` and a `_pre_put_hook(self)`

In `_post_get_hook` you would store away the original value of the property
and in _pre_put_hook you would check that it is the same as the original value unless the original value is `None`.

ie

```
class Spam(ndb.Model):

    eggs =  ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def _post_get_hook(cls,key,future):
        obj = future.get_result()
        obj._my_eggs_prop = obj.eggs

    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        if hasattr(self,'_my_eggs_prop'):
            if self.eggs != self._my_eggs_prop:
               if self._my_eggs_prop != None:
                    # do some logging.
                    raise ValueError
        else:
            setattr(self,'_my_eggs_prop',self.eggs)
            # if the saved value doesn't exist, create it and store
            # the value in case an update occurs after the initial put
            # this also means the object was created and not get()
```

Here is an example of it working

```
s~lightning-catfish> import spam
s~lightning-catfish> x = spam.Spam(id='canned')
s~lightning-catfish> x.eggs = 'green'
s~lightning-catfish> x.put()
Key('Spam', 'canned')
s~lightning-catfish> y = x.key.get()
s~lightning-catfish> y._my_eggs_prop
u'green'
s~lightning-catfish> y.eggs = 'blue'
s~lightning-catfish> y.put()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3232, in _put
    return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File "/home/timh/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3247, in _put_async
    self._pre_put_hook()
  File "spam.py", line 18, in _pre_put_hook
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

The downside of this approach is you could change the property rely in it for some additional code and then only find out about it when you do the put.  However that may not be so bad, as you should in theory not have any code that is modifying the property once changed. So you want to log, and track down how this could be occurring.  Alternately you could reset the value to the original setting, but then you leave incorrect code in place.

A custom property takes a little more thought ;-)

Comment: Thanks. This looks interesting. I'll try it later and tick it if it works. There's no need for the property to ever change once it's set. The bigger goal is to do something like `json.dumps(model.to_dict())` to pass a copy of some entity to a JS client. Then, the client should be able to send that struct back, mutated, and using something like `model.populate(**json.loads(self.request.body))`, write the changes to the model. It's being able to constrain what can be mutated *within the Model definition* that would make this much more elegant. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I never could get this to work. The names don't get bound to the right objects??

Comment: Sorry, a couple of errors in that code.  Just edited it and now it works.  The major error is _pre_put_hook is not a classmethod. I don't know why I stuck that in there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I tried your code, and was still able to mutate `eggs` freely. I tried changing the body of the `_pre_put_hook` function to just read `if hasattr(self,'_my_eggs_prop'): raise ValueError` and it still mutates??

Comment: Ok, my example doesn't stop the value from changing, but prevents you from committing the change.  Preventing the change at the property level will require a custom property.

Comment: In addition, if you create a new object, put it, then modify the property and put, it will update the entity.  To prevent this the _pre_put_hook needs to set `_my_eggs_prop` if it doesn't exist, to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I could put it too. It didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Well it works with the exceptions I mentioned.  I can't see you code so I have no idea what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do what you want with a validator.

`(prop,value)` are the property instance and value to set.  You don't have a handle in the validator for the instance of the class and therefore the pre-existing value.  All the methods of the property you need to get the existing value need a model instance as an argument - like _has_value .  The docs

> Will be called with arguments (prop, value) and should either return
>   the (possibly coerced) value or raise an exception. Calling the
>   function again on a coerced value should not modify the value further.
>   (For example, returning value.strip() or value.lower() is fine, but
>   not value + '$'.) May also return None, which means "no change". See
>   also Writing Property Subclasses
>   `https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options

You will need to write a custom property to manage the state of the value and prevent overwriting once set.

See the example below showing you that you haven't got access to the pre-existing value of the property and a validator isn't passed it or the instance of the model which would have the value.

```
s~lightning-catfish> from pdb import set_trace
s~lightning-catfish> def valid(prop,val):
...    set_trace()
...    return val
... 
s~lightning-catfish> class X(ndb.Model):
...    x = ndb.StringProperty(validator=valid)
... 
s~lightning-catfish> y = X(x="abc")
> <console>(3)valid()
(Pdb) p prop
StringProperty('x', validator=<function valid at 0xaf2d02c>)

(Pdb) p prop._has_value
<bound method StringProperty._has_value of StringProperty('x', validator=<function valid at 0xaf2d02c>)>
(Pdb) p prop._has_value()
*** TypeError: TypeError('_has_value() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)',)
(Pdb) c
s~lightning-catfish> y
X(x='abc')
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a bit back in about the validator from you original question so that anyone searching can also see that validator won't work.

Comment: Added an example of use hooks to provide the functionality

Comment: Restored the ref to `validate`.